# How to install JQueryUI API xml files to NetBeans IDE

Tags: jquery, xml, api, jquery-ui, netbeans

Using the directory C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\ide\docs, I have found the jquery-api.xml file. This file helps me with the needed documentation on JQuery API since auto completion alone is not enough.

I have found the JQueryUi API in xml format. However, after pasting this file in the above directory, I still get the message 'Documentation not Found' after auto completion.

Can someone help me know how to get both documentations working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no any topics on the internet on this topic. Very little research can be done since no articles on the subject after 6 good hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure but you might need to clean your cache so this XML file gets re-scanned. To locate cache directory, start NetBeans and open Help->About, the opened dialog shows cache dir location. Close NetBeans, remove the directory and start NetBeans again.